# In a hand of 5 cards drawn from 52, what is the probability that you draw at least 1 two-card suit?

Tags: probability

My attempt: $$\frac{C_{13,2}C_{4,1}C_{39,3}-(C_{13,2})^2C_{4,1}C_{3,1}C_{26,1}}{C_{52,5}}=0.367$$
Basically I subtracted the chance of getting 2 two card suites from the chance of getting 1 two card suit, to avoid the overlap. Is my reasoning, and answer, correct?

Comment: What about a triple suit?

Comment: By "two-card suit" I mean exactly two cards of the same suit, so not a triple suit

Comment: I would guess that it's easier to calculate the probability to fail. It seems easier to calculate the probability of getting either 3-1-1, 4-1 or flush rather than 2-1-1-1, 2-2-1 or 3-2.

Comment: The two-two case is double-counted, instead of $\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}$ you need $\binom{4}{2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost right, except $\binom41\binom31$ should be $\binom42$, since it doesn't matter which of the two suits you select first.